# How do I count the number of times a value occurs in a csv file with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that contains a list of hotels and their star ratings (1 star through 5 stars). 

Column B hosts each hotel's star rating, beginning in row 2 (row 1 is the header "Review Stars"), one star value per cell (1 - 5). 
I need to write a script for Python (v.3.6.4) to count the number of times "5" occurs in the column "Review Stars". Therefore the number of companies who have a 5 star rating. For example if I have 2000 hotels and 800 of them have 5 star ratings, I need python to return "800". 


So far I have written:

```
import csv
from decimal import *
import math
import pandas as pd

with open('ServiceReviews.csv', 'r') as f:
data = csv.reader(f)
for row in f:
    CustomerEmail = row[0]
    ReviewStars = row[1]
    ReferenceID = row[2]
    BusinessUnitID = row[3]
    Tags = row[4]
    for value in ReviewStars:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'5':list(ReviewStars)})
        fives = df['5'].value_counts()
        print (fives)
```

This returns a list of all of the "5"'s but not a total. I've tried several other panda calls. Anyone have any new insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for Pandas here. You can use `collections.Counter` from the standard library:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('ServiceReviews.csv', 'r') as f:
    c = Counter(row[1] for row in csv.reader(f))
```

The `Counter` object `c` will be a dictionary of counts, with number of stars as keys and respective counts as values. So you can use `c[5]` to extract the number of 5* hotels.

Comment: So he would want to use c[5] to get the total number of the 5 stars right?

Comment: @lamorach, Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ServiceReviews.csv')
df_result = df[df['ReviewStars'] == 5]
print(len(df_result))
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ServiceReviews.csv')
df_result = df[df['ReviewStars'] == 5].count()
print(df_result)
```

Comment: Or `(df['ReviewStarts'] == 5).sum()`.